# What is a good practice to achieve vertical placement? (e.g. a Titlepage)

Tags: formatting, vertical-alignment, titles

**My titlepage looks right now like this:**

[image]

**using this code:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,titlepage,german,final]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

\begin{flushright}
\textbf{\textsc{University XY}}\\
{\small{\textsf{Department Z\\}}}
\end{flushright}

\begin{center}
\bigskip
{\huge{Masterthesis}}\\
\bigskip
{\huge{\textbf{How to vertical align in Latex}}}\\
\bigskip
{\today}\\
\end{center}

\textbf{Author}
\smallskip
\hrule
\smallskip
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Some: & texts \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

---

What I would like to know is, how I should define the *placements* of the text-elements properly and not as some gross, linebreak, lineskip disaster.

Where I would like to place the elemets:

1. the *Univerity* should stay at the top-right corner, right aligned
2. the *author* and following, should be at the bottom, left aligned, and in any case stay on this page
3. the *title* should be at the center between the *University* and the *author*
4. *Masterthesis* should be at between *University* and *title*
5. the *date* should be between *title* and *author*
6. I would like to be able to easily move *Title*, *Masterthesis* and *date* (to change their relative vertical distance)

Of course I could hack something, so that the output would met these requirements, but I am looking for a sound, a nice and dynamic solution - lacking of that much experience, I hope someone else has it. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm  sure your university has a design guide. Has your university also templates for masterthesis (maybe in Word, better LaTeX?). For eample `classicthesis` could be a solution, but it depends on the given rules of your university. For German language I knew a few templates.

Comment: Well, I found some templates, but not exactly from my University, which seems to have different style/design requirements even through the different workgroups of my department. However there seems not to be anything in Tex, at least not officially, so I am adapting to what is required and what I have seen in other works, but the Tex is up to me right now. Many thanks for the tip though! I looked up `classicthesis` - it looks very nice, this will surely help too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a proposal:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,titlepage,final]{scrreprt}

\newcommand{\centeredelement}[2][]{\begingroup\centering#1#2\par\endgroup}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{flushright}
{\bfseries\scshape University XY}\\
{\small\sffamily Department Z\par}
\end{flushright}

\vspace{\stretch{.25}}

\centeredelement[\huge]{%
  Masterthesis
}

\vspace{\stretch{.25}}

\centeredelement[\huge\bfseries]{%
   How to vertical align in \LaTeX
}

\vspace{\stretch{.25}}

\centeredelement{\today}

\vspace{\stretch{.25}}

\textbf{Author}
\par
\smallskip
\hrule
\smallskip
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
Some: & texts \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

With `\centeredelement` we set something to the center; the optional argument consists of the font changes to be made.

You can play with the arguments to `\stretch`; here they are all equal, but you can set them to the fraction of space you prefer between the two elements.

[image]

Comment: Nice! Is `\stretch` provided by `koma`, or is it "available everywhere"?

Comment: @Brent.Longborough It's a standard command in the LaTeX kernel.

Comment: Nice indeed! Works like a charm, but could you explain, why you created the `centeredelement` command? Because using `\begin{center}` works too - so what is the advantage?

Comment: @Jook Actually `center` adds vertical space (as does `flushright`, to be honest). A personal command has the biggest advantage in being redefinable at will; so, if you finally opt for left aligned elements, you'd have only to act on the definition only.

Comment: @egreg: Is `\stretch` equivalent to using `\hfill`s?

Comment: @ℝaphink In this particular case `\vfill` instead of `\vspace{\stretch{.25}}` would give the same result. But it's preferable to use `\stretch` so that the proportions between the spacings can be adjusted easily by acting on the fractions.

Comment: What happens if the total is not 1?

Comment: @ℝaphink You just have to do "harder" math.

Comment: @egreg: Well then I don't really see the difference with `\hfill` where it's just weights according to how many you put.